# Swap between Azure Colated Caching and InProc

Tags: azure, session-state, azure-storage, azure-web-roles, azure-caching

I have setup the Web Roles to use colocated caching.  The problem is that during development we don't want to have to run the emulator all the time (as it is quite cumbersome).

Running our web applications normally (not emulated in a Web Role) fails because of the Azure session state provider:

> [InvalidOperationException: role discovery data is unavailable]
>   Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime.RoleEnvironment.get_Roles() +171

**Is it possible to configure caching to use normal InProc when not running in a Web Role and to use Azure Colocated Caching when running in a Web Role.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The session state configuration is located in the web.config, so you could create a config override with the standard web.config transformations for your local development and then when you deploy it make sure to switch to the config that has the reference to the Azure Caching provider.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2009/05/04/web-deployment-web-config-transformation.aspx

**UPDATE**: Adding notes from comments below.
You can also add some code prior to the start of the website to programatically swap out the providers.  There is the ability to do this on the web role start up (http://blog.elastacloud.com/2011/05/13/azure-howto-programmatically-modify-web-config-on-webrole-startup/) or with a simple (Synchronous) start up task.  By doing this work in the role OnStart or the start up task you remove the necessity for the Asp.NET site to have a dependency on the Azure Runtime to detect if it is running in Azure or not and the config is completed before the IIS website is started.

Comment: Thanks for the answer!  Would it not be possible to do this in code?  Like some kind of dynamic provider.  The web.config transformation doesn't fit with our release process very well.

Comment: Yes, you could do this in code. If you created your own implementation of the Session State Provider (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.sessionstate.sessionstatestoreproviderbase.aspx) and within that implementation detect if you are running in Azure and then route to either InProc or Azure Caching providers as appropriate.  You'll likely need to do some wiring around the configuration so that both are there in your config and you can configure them completely in code.  

The transform can be part of the build so I'm not sure why it would not fit with your release process.

Comment: @MikeWo Jumping in :). I'm just curious if we can programmatically change config section in web.config on application startup? By default we could just go with InProc and if we detect the role is running in Windows Azure Cloud Service (i.e. we get `RoleEnvironment = true`), we remove that section from web.config and insert a new section for distributed cache. Any thoughts?

Comment: @GauravMantri Yes, I was thinking about this on the drive to work as well. Doing the swap on RoleEntry OnStart should be possible because you'd have access to the web.config prior to ASP.NET application start up.  Personally, I still be more inclined to deal with this as part of the deployment process, but doing it at start up would work.

Comment: @MikeWo Thanks. Doing it on role's start up won't work because what I've seen is that web.config is not accessible at that time (I may be wrong though). Ideal place would be to do it in `Application_Startup` event.

Comment: @GauravMantri it should be accessible to alter. Check out this older article: http://blog.elastacloud.com/2011/05/13/azure-howto-programmatically-modify-web-config-on-webrole-startup/.  He gets access by using web administration, which takes away the concern of knowing where the web.config file is, but relies on the convention of the IIS naming of the sites which could change.  Another option is a synchronous start up task to locate the file and make the change. This has the possible benefit of the asp.net code having 0 azure runtime dependency if not running the cloud.

Comment: @GauravMantri I've not tried altering the web.config in application_Start of a website.  Won't changing the web.config at that point cause a recycle of the app pool and cause the Application_start to fire again?